# How to develop the ui layouts for an android wear application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, user-interface, wear-os

I have setup my eclipse and made it that when you install my app on your phone it will automatically(if paired with your android wear device) come onto the person's android wear device. But I have tested out all these apps that work just like me and i have seen that the ui elements all look very similar. How do i design my apps. I am pretty sure i have to use more than the palette in eclipse, but do i have to use some screen designer software, or is there some specific code i have to write? Is there anything to import for designing the layouts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this question not a proper question? Is it too broad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio has a great visual editor for creating UI layouts for Android Wear. It has a lot of support to help you with this, and if you are getting started with Android Wear, this is the best tool to start working with. I would only recommend using Eclipse for legacy applications where you are already using Eclipse and you cannot easily change over.

Comment: In fact, that is my case, i have 9 apps built on eclipse, this android wear app is almost done, I currently just need to finish the design aspect. So i am not sure if I can switch over to android  studio easily...

Comment: Never mind. I migrated my project to Android Studio, and the visual editor is good.